# MongoDB Spring - No bean named 'mongoTemplate' is defined

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

This is probably a common question regarding using Mongodb and Spring. I didn't expected to be asking here questions, because every time when I got stuck I could find the solutions here. But this time none of the already answered questions regarding this topic could help me to solve the problem...

I have seriously no clue what to do... Here is the situation:

This is my application context (ONE-servletConfig.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="nl.company.department.project.controller.controllers,nl.company.department.project.mongodb"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property value="WEB-INF/jsp/" name="prefix" />
    <property value=".jsp" name="suffix" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />


<mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" host="abcdefgh.mlab.com"
    port="123456" credentials="apple:pie@appledb" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="opadb" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" />

<mongo:repositories base-package="nl.company.department.project.mongodb"
    mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</bean>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.0">
<display-name>ONE</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ONEapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/ONE-servletConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ONEapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My repositories is in the package nl.company.department.project.mongodb
One of the repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

}
```

In my controller I have autowired this repository and when I use method on userCollection it will work en return values of the database. This is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("consultants")
public class OPAController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userCollection;

    more code ...
}
```

The user object looks like this:

```
@Document(collection="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Getter @Setter private String name;
    @Getter @Setter private String password;
}
```

I wanted to use Spring Security, so i created a couple of classes...

The security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/consultants/sendPassword","/consultants/authenticateUser")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

And the SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
    super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

And the CustomAuthenticationProvider class

```
@Component
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "nl.company.department.project.mongodb")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userCollection;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (userCollection.findOne(name) != null && userCollection.findOne(name).getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

So autowiring the repository in the controller works, but when I want to use the repository in CustomAuthenticationProvider class it will throw a the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userCollection': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoTemplate' is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoTemplate' is defined
```

But the strange part is that i did defined the mongoTemplate and it worked in the controller. Can you guys see what I did wrong, maybe i missed something in the configuration...?

Comment: try changing 

    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.company.department.project.controller.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.company.department.project.mongodb"></context:component-scan>

to

    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.company.department.project.controller.controllers,nl.company.department.project.mongodb"/>

Comment: I changed it but it will give me the same error as before

Comment: update the qstn with package where UserRepository  located..

Comment: Yes, i added the package of the UserRepository

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below pls:

```
<mongo:db-factory dbname="mongoDb" host="mongoServer" port="mongoPort"/>


<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.basePackage"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but it won't work. I have the idea that springfilter is causing this issue. I have another class that will initialize Spring Security:

    public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

     public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
      super(SecurityConfig.class);
     }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add @Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity annotations to SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```